# Как изменить цвет svg объекта, добавленного с помощью img?

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg, filter

Я добавляю svg изображение в HTML разметку с помощью тега `<img>`.
Изображение чёрно-белое. Необходимо закрасить его, допустим в синий или зелёный цвет.

Применение правил CSS для svg `fill`, `stroke` не даёт нужного эффекта.

```css
.img1 {
fill:dodgerblue; 
stroke:white;
path:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
width:30vw;
height:30vh;
}
</style>
```

```html
<img class="img1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/181/181549.svg">
```

Есть ли другие способы получить нужный результат?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть еще один способ. Всем элементам img с svg в разметке добавим класс .svg, затем выберем и заменим их на svg с помощью Javascript.

> Не работает в [IE11, Opera Mini](https://caniuse.com/fetch)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img.svg').forEach(img => {
    var imgId = img.id;
    var imgClass = img.className;
    var imgURL = img.src;
    var imgFill = img.getAttribute('data-fill');
    
    fetch(imgURL).then(r => r.text()).then(text => {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
        var svg = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
        
        if (typeof imgId !== 'undefined') {
            svg.setAttribute('id', imgId);
        }
        
        if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            svg.setAttribute('class', imgClass);
        }        
        
        if (typeof imgFill !== 'undefined') {
            svg.setAttribute('fill', imgFill);
        }
        
        img.parentNode.replaceChild(svg, img);
        
    }).catch(console.error);
    
});
```

```css
.svg {
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  -webkit-transition: fill 280ms ease;
  -moz-transition: fill 280ms ease;
  -ms-transition: fill 280ms ease;
  -o-transition: fill 280ms ease;
  transition: fill 280ms ease;
}
.svg:hover {
  fill: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#test2 {
  fill:orange;
}
#test2:hover {
  fill:purple;
}
```

```html
<img class="svg test1" data-fill="blue" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/32/32441.svg">
<img class="svg test2" id="test2" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/181/181549.svg">
<img class="svg test3" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/181/181549.svg">
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('img[src$=svg]')`

Comment: @Pavel Благодарю за ваш вариант ответа.

Comment: а если к примеру будет не сколько фигур и надо им по отдельности изменить заливку и обводку ?  хотя это уже круто ...

Comment: @MaximLensky можно использовать data-fill, data-stroke для каждого из img тэга, и при замене использовать данные для подмены атрибутов в самом svg. svg.setAttribute('fill', imgFill); где imgFill = img.getAttribute('data-fill'), или добавить к заменяемым svg обработку ID и использовать тот же css

Comment: @MaximLensky обновил ответ

Comment: вы не поняли меня ...я имею ввиду внутри SVG будут треугольник круг и квадрат ... и их по отдельности закрасить по разному но нет три img

Comment: @MaximLensky схема та же: выбираем нужную path например и ставим атрибут fill svg.querySelector('path:nth-child(1)').setAttribute('fill',imgFill); Но опять-таки, зачем, если есть CSS...

Answer (score 7):

Когда файл SVG добавлен на страницу HTML с помощью тега `<img>`, то он ничем не отличается от обычного изображения растрового формата. Поэтому невозможно применить стили из внешней таблицы.

*Но есть возможность изменить цвет фигур svg с помощью фильтров CSS или SVG.*

Цвет SVG фильтра можно установить любой.

- В примере ниже изображение будет покрашено в синий цвет

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#d3d3d3;
overflow:hidden;
}
.container:hover {
background:black;
}
img {
filter:url(#filter_B);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://www.stupidedia.org/images/a/a3/Gangsta-balz-transparent.svg">
</div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="0" height="0">  
    <defs>
       
        <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="filter_B">
           <feFlood flood-color="dodgerblue"/>
           <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="xor" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Используя два фильтра, можно реализовать эффект наведения:

```
img {
filter:url(#filter_B);
}
img:hover {
filter:url(#filter_G);
}
```

**Ниже полный код:**

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#d3d3d3;
overflow:hidden;

}
.container:hover {
  background: black;
}
img {
  filter: url(#filter_B);
}
img:hover {
  filter: url(#filter_G);
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.stupidedia.org/images/a/a3/Gangsta-balz-transparent.svg">
</div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0">  
    <defs>
       <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="filter_G">
         <feFlood flood-color="yellowgreen"/>
         <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="xor" />
      </filter>   
        <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="filter_B">
           <feFlood flood-color="dodgerblue"/>
           <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="xor" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Всегда интересовал подобный подход через img, спасибо за объяснение и примеры.

Answer (score 2):

### JS + svg filter

Можно добавлять svg фильтры с помощью JS. В нашем случае будет использован фильтр
`filter:hue-rotate(120deg)`, который cработает при клике на svg

```html
<img id="img" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/car.svg" style="cursor:pointer" width="350" height="350" >

<script>
img.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  img.style.cssText = "filter:hue-rotate(170deg);cursor:pointer;"
})
</script>
```

**Изменение цвета фильтра на альтернативный**

```html
<img id="img" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/ca.svg" style="cursor:pointer" width="200" height="200" >

<script>
let angle = 120;
img.addEventListener("click",()=>{
   angle *= -1;
  img.style.cssText = `filter:hue-rotate(${angle}deg);cursor:pointer;`
  })
</script>
```